# Adding peers from another torrent with different hash values

Tags: utorrent, hashing

I found two exact torrent files (same in size) with two different hash values. Since the contents of the files were the same and the number of seeds was very less, I thought that I could connect the seeds from the other file in order to increase the seed count.

Both the files did not have the trackers and they only had [DHT], [Local Peer Discovery] and [Peer Exchange]. So, I tried to add the peers using "Add Peer" option by copying the selected host from the other file, but it was not successful.

As I am technically not fluent, I expect somebody to explain me what to do?
(FYI, when I clicked the magnet links of both files, they save as separate files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. if the hash is different, then the file is different, and you can't mix them.

BT performs hashes on every piece of the file as well, so even if the files were identical but misaligned by a single bit, every one of the hash values would be different, and each piece that did not match its expected hash as described in the torrent file will be seen as corrupt, and the algorithm will attempt to download them all over again. That means that even if the overall hashes matched exactly, it would be unlikely that the piece hashes would match.